# Preload assets into NSURLCache

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

We have a mobile app that has several static assets.  Especially relevant is the 440k of "vendor" javascript ... stuff like Backbone and jQuery and various plugins and add-ons to the aforementioned.  The vendor stuff changes less often than the ios app itself ... maybe once every couple months.  Thus it's a prime candidate for preloading into the app image we are distributing through Apple.  My question is: how do I preload NSURLCache with as asset where I have the bits?

Ideally, I'd:

1) bundle vendor_assets.js into my app's distribution

2) on launch, call something like [NSURLCache preloadAsset: "vendor_assets.js", [NSData fromFile: "vendor_assets.js]]

3) load the UIWebView, which then requests "vendor_assets.js" (plus all the other files

4) because "vendor_assets.js is already in the cache, we save the user 440k of download bandwidth.  faster launch times.  more money.  promotions. champagne. glory. eternal fulfillment.  all that shtuff.

How on earth do I do this?  I've been banging my head against this wall all day, and so far, all I have is a bloody forehead.

Answer (score 3):

I just created a NSurLCache subclass specifically for this situation. You can find it at: https://github.com/evermeer/EVURLCache

Comment: I ended up doing something pretty extensive based on creating a custom NSURLProtocol.  It fetches a gzipped tarball from a well-known path and will serve static assets from that.  It works VERY well and has eliminated network delay entirely from our app launch.  We are looking at opensourceing the implementation at some point in the next few months (ie, whenever I get around to it).